# \triangleleft and \bowtie

Tags: symbols

I want to redefine the command `\triangleleft` so that it always has the color green:

```
\let\oldtriangleleft\triangleleft
\renewcommand\triangleleft{\textcolor{green}{\oldtriangleleft}}
```

When I use the command `$\bowtie$`, it complains "Missing { inserted." It is because `\bowtie` is defined based on `\triangleleft`? In that case, is there a fix?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to redefine `\triangleleft`; it's just a generic name and you should use a new name that reflects the meaning of the green symbol.

Comment: @egreg I appreciate your comment. However, I'm still curious as to whether there's a way to get around the problem I mentioned :)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Why the additional braces with `\textcolor`? There no need for it and it's surely preferable to `\color` in math mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO it is not a good idea to re-define it. But if you have a reason for that: `\bowtie` is defined robustly as

```
\mathrel \triangleright \joinrel \mathrel \triangleleft
```

So you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\let\oldtriangleleft\triangleleft
\renewcommand\triangleleft{\mathbin{\color{green}\oldtriangleleft}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\bowtie{\mathrel\triangleright\joinrel\mathrel\oldtriangleleft}

\begin{document}

\[A\oldtriangleleft B\]
\[A\triangleleft B\]
\[A\bowtie B\]

\end{document}
```

Notice that I put the new `\triangleleft` inside `\mathbin` to make it a binary operator, conserving the spacing of the original one.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Redefining commands always carries some risks, if that command is used by other ones. This is one case.

There's no general rule, unfortunately, for telling whether a redefinition can harm other commands. You've found that `\triangleleft` is used by `\bowtie` and it's almost obvious that there's a problem, because `\bowtie` is defined by

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bowtie}{%
  \mathrel\triangleright\joinrel\mathrel\triangleleft}
```

in `fontmath.ltx`. What you should do is thus

```
\let\oldtriangleleft\triangleleft
\renewcommand\triangleleft{\textcolor{green}{\oldtriangleleft}}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\bowtie}{%
  \mathrel\triangleright\joinrel\mathrel\oldtriangleleft}
```

and `\bowtie` will use the "uncolored" triangle.

However, I don't recommend this path. Rather, define a new command for the green triangle, reflecting its intended meaning.

If the green triangle left is to be used in the same way as the black one, I suggest to declare it as a binary operation (`\triangleleft` *is* a binary relation symbol):

```
\renewcommand\triangleleft{\mathbin{\textcolor{green}{\oldtriangleleft}}}
```